# Mongodb - Find if date field is within last 10 mins or get date difference

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am using mongodb in a react app and the following query

```
  let editedTime =  await req.db.collection('commentsPosts').findOne( 
    {
      "_id": req.query.whenEditedId
    }
  )
  res.json({editedTime});
```

gives me the following result

```
{"editedTime":{"_id":"abcd","text":"this was edited","editedAt":"2020-08-09T23:37:31.279Z"}}
```

How to find if editedAt was within last 10 mins OR is there something to get the date difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Date Object from your editedAt property and substract with actual Date, you will get the milliseconds difference, then you can convert to minutes with the function below.

```js
let response = {"editedTime":{"_id":"abcd","text":"this was edited","editedAt":"2020-08-09T23:37:31.279Z"}}

let editedAt = new Date(response.editedTime.editedAt);
let actualDate = new Date();

let difference = actualDate - editedAt;
console.log(difference);

function millisToMinutes(millis) {
  var minutes = Math.floor(millis / 60000);
  return minutes;
}

console.log(millisToMinutes(difference) + ' minutes');
```

Comment: That should work but its a javascript solution. A mongodb solution might help. Your answer deserves upvotes though.

Answer (score 1):

To find a date which falls in last 10 minutes,

```
db.collection.find({
 editedAt : { 
       $gte: new Date().getTime() - 60000);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using JavaScript `Date` objects for your timestamps. This is good, but it is important to distinguish that from numeric timestamps. Since some people may use numeric timestamps, I'll include that answer for completeness.

Note: the difference is basically just a matter of wrapping the numeric timestamp in a `new Date(...)` if necessary.

Also note: it is very easy to make a mistake converting milliseconds to 10 minutes, so the math is left for the JavaScript engine. You can quickly convert it to `600000` and use that if you want, but I like being clear about what is happening.

## Retrieve records with date after 10 minutes ago

#### Using JavaScript Date

```
let editedTime =  await req.db.collection('commentsPosts').findOne( 
  {
    $gte: new Date(Date.now() - (1000 * 60 * 10))
  }
)
res.json({editedTime});
```

### Using numeric timestamps

```
let editedTime =  await req.db.collection('commentsPosts').findOne( 
  {
    $gte: Date.now() - (1000 * 60 * 10)
  }
)
res.json({editedTime});
```

## Calculate time difference

### Using JavaScript Date

Note: I have not tested this, but the mongo library *should* return a `Date` object if that's what you're using, therefore you can use `Date` functions like `getTime()` to convert to milliseconds. If you want `timeSince` to be in a different unit other than milliseconds, you'll need to convert the number.

```
res.json({timeSince: Date.now() - editedTime.editedAt.getTime()})
```

### Using numeric timestamps

```
res.json({timeSince: Date.now() - editedTime.editedAt})
```